# Function nested call in Postgresql

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.5

When I execute Test1() it gives me output but when I execute Test2() it gives following error

> structure of query does not match function result type
>
> Returned type record does not match expected type numeric in column 1.

Can anyone please suggest me what I have missed.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION "Test1" (i_emp_id double precision, OUT o_emp_term_detail_id double precision, OUT o_term_id double precision, OUT o_term_start_date timestamp without time zone)
    RETURNS record
    LANGUAGE plpgsql
    SECURITY DEFINER
    AS $function$
     begin
    //logic
    END;
    $function$;

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION "Test2"(i_emp_id double precision, OUT o_emp_term_detail_id double precision, OUT o_term_id double precision, OUT o_term_start_date timestamp without time zone)
RETURNS record
LANGUAGE plpgsql
SECURITY DEFINER
AS $function$
   begin
select Test1(i_emp_id);
END;
$function$;
```

Comment: When we return value from one function to another function.Is there any other way to achieve this please help me.

Answer (score 0):

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION "Test1" (i_emp_id double precision, OUT o_emp_term_detail_id double precision, OUT o_term_id double precision, OUT o_term_start_date timestamp without time zone)
RETURNS SETOF record
LANGUAGE plpgsql
SECURITY DEFINER
AS $function$
begin
 return query values(1.1::float,1.1::float,now()::timestamp);
END;
$function$;
```

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION "Test2"(i_emp_id double precision, OUT o_emp_term_detail_id double precision, OUT o_term_id double precision, OUT o_term_start_date timestamp without time zone)
RETURNS SETOF record
LANGUAGE plpgsql
SECURITY DEFINER
AS $function$
begin
    RETURN QUERY select * FROM  "Test1"(i_emp_id) t;
END;
$function$;
```

There are several syntactical issues with your query.   Here's a working example based on your inputs.

Comment: Thanks Kirk Roybal

Comment: if this satisfied your question, please accept the answer